# using Fermat's little Theorem to find the least residue of $5^{38}\ mod\ 13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

please help me work this out i have no clue thanks Using Fermat’s little theorem, find the least residue of $5^{38}$ modulo $13$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 2):

Fermat's Little theorem tells you that $5^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$. 
And, $5^{38}= (5^{12})^3 5^2$.

Comment: thank you so that means the least residue is 1 right?

Comment: @stacey no it is $25 = 12$ mod 13

Comment: ok now I've got it thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can also use fermat as follow (modula 13):
$$5\cdot 5^{38}\equiv5^{\color{#80f}{39}}\equiv 5^{\color{#80f}{3\cdot 13}}\equiv (\color{#0a0}{5^{13}})^3\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{Fermat}}\equiv (\color{#0a0}{5})^3 \mod 13$$

so we have $$\color{#80f}5\cdot 5^{38}\equiv \color{#80f}5.5^2\mod 13$$
hence $$5^{38}\equiv 5^2 \equiv 25\equiv 13+12\equiv 12\mod 13 $$

Answer (score 0):

W/O using Fermat's Little Thereom,

$5^2\equiv-1\pmod{13},5^{38}=(5^2)^{19}\equiv(-1)^{19}$

Answer (score 0):

By Fermat $\,5\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, 5^{\color{#0a0}{12}}\equiv 1\pmod{13},\,$ so $\,38\equiv 2\pmod{\color{#0a0}{12}}\,\Rightarrow\, 5^{38}\equiv 5^2\pmod{13}\,$ by

**Key Idea** $ $ Generally if $\,a^e\equiv 1\pmod m\,$ then exponents on $\,a\,$ can be taken mod $\,e,\,$ i.e. $\,\ j\equiv k\,\pmod e\ \Rightarrow\ a^{\large j}\equiv a^{\large k}\pmod m\,\ $ since

$$ \begin{array}{}\color{#c00}{a^{\large e}\equiv 1}\\ j = k\! +\! en\end{array}\Rightarrow\,\ a^{\large j}\equiv a^{\large  k+en}\equiv a^{\large  k}\color{#c00}{(a^{\large  e})}^{\large  n}\equiv a^{\large  k}\color{#c00}{(1)}^{\large  n}\equiv a^k\!\!\pmod m\qquad $$